# Spring mvc Controller returns jsp code instead of jsp page

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

my Spring mvc controller  returns Jsp code instead of jsp page

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authenticate")  
    public ModelAndView dashboard(HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
    { 
        String username=request.getParameter("userName");
        String pws=request.getParameter("pws");

        System.out.println(username+pws); 



        return new ModelAndView("dashboard");       
    }
```

so, its returning whole `jsp code of dasboard`.

but want to return a view jsp. why its returning code ?

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Scheduling Portal</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

**edit**

if request is

```
@RequestMapping(value="/")
```

instead of

```
@RequestMapping(value="/authenticate")
```

then it returns jsp page.

i am adding servlet.xml to review it please get me a solution
please look at **servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">    

     <!-- welcome page -->
      <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="login"/> 

     <!-- add AspectJ autoproxy support for AOP -->


    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
        <aop:include name="CmsLoggingAspect"/>
    </aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

    <bean id="CmsLoggingAspect" class="com.rasvek.cms.aspect.CmsLoggingAspect"/>  

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->       
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rasvek.cms" >

  </context:component-scan>   

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/> 

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->    
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />     
    </bean> 
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> 
    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/campus_guru_01?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />

      <!--    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://aahbs06vwbadaq.ccmhxvps7vly.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306" />
        <property name="user" value="CampusGuruDB" />
        <property name="password" value="campusgurur" />   -->   

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->  
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />  
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" /> 
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />    
    </bean>    

    <!-- Difine multipart Resolver for file upload -->
     <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

        <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

    </bean>

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory --> 
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.rasvek.cg.entity" />  
        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
           <props>  
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    
<tx:annotation-driven/>   
    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">  
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>   

</beans>
```

do i need to change anything in my servlet.xml  ?

Comment: Put your jsp code pls and is there any error on page ? Or just jsp code ?

Comment: dashborad. jsp or login.jsp ?.only jsp code there is no error

Comment: Do you have web.xml file ?

Comment: yes i do have..

Comment: Put it in your question please

Comment: please have a look on web.xml

Comment: Try to replace in web.xml <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> with <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your servlet is not or not properly configured. You need something like this in your servlet.xml. This is to render the right jsps to the view.

```
  <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  </bean>
```

And by the way. Why aren't you using the @RequestParam and @PathVariable to receive your parameter. It's way easier.

I suggest to adjust your servlet.xml like this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/>      
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

This way you get the resource conversion from your http requests and responses.

Comment: can you post your spring.xml?

Comment: i have added servlet.xml please look at it